I use Scala 3.3.3 and would like to test a small program using import cats.kernel.laws.IsEq - I get this error: laws is not a member of cats.kernel
I am using Scala 3.3.3 and would like to test a small program using import cats.kernel.laws.IsEq, I get this error message: "laws" is not a member of cats.kernel and here is my
build.sbt:
val scala3Version = "3.3.0"

lazy val root = project
  .in(file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "CheckAll",
    version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT",
    scalaVersion := scala3Version,

    // Dependencies
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      // Cats Core and Laws dependencies
      "org.typelevel" %% "cats-core" % "2.9.0",
      "org.typelevel" %% "cats-laws" % "2.9.0" % Test,

      // ScalaTest for testing
      "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.9" % Test,

      // MUnit for testing (optional, you can remove this if you prefer ScalaTest)
      "org.scalameta" %% "munit" % "0.7.29" % Test
    )
  )

and here is my program:
package scala

import cats.*
import cats.kernel.laws.IsEq
import cats.kernel.instances.int.*

@main
def hello(): Unit =
  println("Hello world!")

def myIsEq =

  val a = 42
  val b = 42

  val isEqual: IsEq[Int] = IsEq(a, b)

your text
I tried to run the program

You added cats-laws in the Test scope

Thank you very much Mateusz for taking time to look into it. You are right that was the problem. :-)
